# Is there an option in intellij to generate tables from our classes (entities)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

How to generate database tables from entity classes with jpa hibernate. Using the IntelliJ IDE.

Because I created my entities with the jpa annotations, I also created the data source and tested the connection. But I don't know what to do afterwards so that these classes are transformed into tables in my database

Comment: Have a look at liquibase. Not exactly what you asked for, but if you don't know about it, you should have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you're also using Spring Boot, you can generate your tables using this spring property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`. But you need to understand that this option generates tables for you, though will not provide you the SQL code. It's usually ok for tests i guess.

Also make sure you have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you don't use spring, there's a hibernate only version too.

```
<!-- In persistence.xml -->
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

OR

```
<!-- In hibernate.cfg.xml -->
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```